# Null Exception of array: not initialising from Oracle database

Tags: c#, arrays, oracle, visual-studio-2013, argumentnullexception

I have connected my Visual studio 2013 to Oracle XE 11 Database. I'm trying to retrieve information from the tables I have in the database using the following code, but it seems that the array decor isn't getting initialised with the values I'm setting it with in the foreach loop.
Please help.

```
conn.Open(); // it is an OleDbConnection

String[] decor;

DataTable table1 = new DataTable();

OleDbDataAdapter oda1 = new OleDbDataAdapter("select name from Product where Commodity_Type='decor'",conn);

oda1.Fill(table1);

int j=0;

foreach (DataRow row in table1.Rows)

            {

                decor[j] = row["name"].ToString();

                j++;

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:
You need to `initialized` decor after filling the table.

```
conn.Open();
DataTable table1 = new DataTable();
OleDbDataAdapter oda1 = new OleDbDataAdapter("select name from Product where Commodity_Type='decor'",conn);
oda1.Fill(table1);
String[] decor = new String[(table1.rows.Count())]
int j=0;
foreach (DataRow row in table1.Rows) {
     decor[j] = row["name"].ToString();
     j++;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You did not initialise the variable `decor`

```
decor = new String[(table1.rows.Count())]
```

and that's the error you should have found by yourself.